# Remove last node from linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

When I run this code, it `return`s the correct number but it doesn't `delete` it afterwards.

I tried several other functions and they don't work either. 
Is there something wrong with my function or should I be looking outside of it?

```
int Stack::remove()
{
  clean = head; //clean is what it to be deleted. Head is the beginning

  while (clean->next != NULL) //stop at the end of list
  {
     clean = clean->next; //move it along
   }

  return clean->number; //this gives me the right number
  delete clean; //but when I print list in main, last item is still there
  clean = NULL; //something about dangling pointers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ANYTHING after the return statement is not executed.

So, copy the clean->number value to some temporary variable, delete clean and return the value of the temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to null out the pointer that points to the node you want to delete -- either the head pointer or the next pointer in the preceding node.

Then you can delete it and return the number.  Also, as Paul indicates, you have to remember the number, delete the node, and THEN return it.

I have always done it this way:

```
if (head == NULL) {
    //return some error condition
}
Node **pclean = &head;
while ((*pclean)->next != NULL) {
    pclean = &((*pclean)->next);
}
int ret = (*pclean)->number;
delete *pclean;
*pclean = NULL;
return ret;
```

This way, we always have the pointer to the pointer to the node, which is what we have to null out.

Now, if this is an assigment, then don't turn in this code -- your prof will know you didn't write it.  Do it without the pointer-to-pointer.